# can time dilation be used to determine if an object is moving

Tags: spacetime, speed, time-dilation

I know that movement is only relative to another object, but as you move faster you also experience time dilation, correct? So if one body is moving faster then it should have a dilation of time, couldn't that be used to determine if one body is moving or if it is the other body. And if that is true then could it be in relation to space-time itself that speed should be measured.

as an example if two people float toward each other in space with no other reference point then each has an equal claim to say the other is the one moving. my question is if there speed was 99% of the speed of light, then there is a good amount of time dilation, so one of the two observers will have less time pass for them. couldn't that be used to say that that observer is the one that is moving

Comment: *"I know that movement is only relative to another object..."* Yet you still ask if we can determine which body is moving? They're both moving relative to each other, so each will observe the other to be time dilated. The whole situation is symmetric, so both objects observe all the same effects.

Comment: The reason there has to be time dilation in the first place is because there is no way to decide which observer is moving.

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer, NO.

Please be aware that all inertial frames are indistinguishable, so there is no "universal inertial frame".

So if you are an observer ($A$) in an inertial frame ($F_A$) and see another observer ($B$) in a different inertial frame ($F_B$) which is moving to you, you beleive that you are at rest, but the observer $B$ who is at rest in his own inertial frame $F_B$ beleives that you are moving towards him.

Say that both reference fames are moving at relativistic speeds, each observer can perform the time dilatation that the other would experience, and the time dialtation that he would experience if he was the one moving.
If you do the math you will notice that both reach to the same results, as there is no way to distinguish between inertial frames, but neither observer can experience such time dilatation, the can only measure the time dilatation of the other inertial frame respective to their own.

Answer (score 0):

> but as you move faster you also experience time dilation, correct?

(1)  Move faster relative to what?  You're at rest with respect to yourself.  According to you, it's the *other* clocks that are moving, not you.  If there a million other clocks 'out there', each with a different velocity relative to you, what would it mean for you to 'move faster'?  If you accelerated for some time, you would be moving faster relative to some of the other clocks and slower relative to the rest.

(2)  You *do* observe that clocks moving relative to you run slower than your clock but your clock is unaffected by these relatively moving clocks.  And, according to the other clocks, your clock runs slow compared to them but, again, this doesn't affect your clock in the slightest.

> so one of the two observers will have less time pass for them.
>   couldn't that be used to say that that observer is the one that is
>   moving

No, it doesn't work that way.  Both observers find that the other's clock runs slow compared to their own clock.  This not a contradiction and it isn't meaningful to ask "but which clock *actually* runs slow".  This has been asked and answered, in different ways, on this site.  Take the time to browse the *Related* side bar for similar questions and answers here.